# Multi threading approach

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have developed the below code using TPL and all works fine except how to restart the task. Currently when I click `button1` the thread starts in `textBox1` and similarly with `button3` and `textBox2`. When I click `button3` and `button4` both the threads get's cancelled.

Now I want to restart the thread where left off on the click event of `button1` and `button3`. I tried many approaches but could not get any idea on how to do this.

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token;
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        token1 = cancellationTokenSource1.Token;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var run = true;
            while (run)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        run = false;
                        break;
                        //token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }
                    // your code
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Action act = () => textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
                    textBox1.Invoke(act);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var run = true;
            while (run)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if (token1.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        run = false;
                        break;
                        //token1.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }
                    // your code
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Action act = () => textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
                    textBox2.Invoke(act);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource1.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you can't `pause` a task with TPL, you can only cancel. if you want to pause you would need to add some kind of a signal event to the code inside the task so you can flag it to stop execution and wait for it to be reset, e.g. look into `AutoResetEvent` class or similar. Note, however, that if the user spawns a few hundred Tasks then the whole app will become fairly sluggish.

Comment: A Task is **not** a thread, it's a *task*. One thing that needs to run in the background. If you want to run many things, you use many tasks. *Instead* of using an infinite loop inside the task as if it were a thread, create the task with `Task.Run` whenever you need to do something

Comment: BTW there's no need to use Invoke either. Just convert your method to `async` and use `await`. The method after await will run on the UI thread and be able to update the textbox directly

Comment: What are you trying to do? Obviously, this is demo code. The problem is that it abuses tasks. You could perform the same with a timer, or a loop with `await Task.Delay(1000,token)` and get rid of almost all the code in `button1_Click`. Tasks don't pause or restart - they represent a *short* job that will run on a single ThreadPool thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sync thread using signaling, generally they are achieved using [Event Wait Handles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksb7zs2x(v=vs.110).aspx) like AutoResetEvent, ManualReset and CountdownEvent. You can achieve this with [ManualReset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Declare ManualResetEvent:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token1;
private ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Modify on CancellationRequest

```
if (token.IsCancellationRequested) {
   run = false;
   mre.WaitOne();
 //token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

OnStart/OnResume: `mre.Set();`

Comment: There's no need to use synchronization is the TPL is used properly. One task can run after another with `ContinueWith` or `await`.

Comment: Not one way - if you have to synchronize, you are doing it wrong. A task is a single job, not a thread. The OP is (ab)using tasks and treating them as if they were threads

Comment: Besides, if you are going to use an event, why use the cancellation token at all? You aren't *cancelling*. You are using something that says *cancel* for a completely different job

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true, I simply believe OP is experimenting and exploring seeing his naming conventions

Comment: This isn't about naming conventions. It's plain-old misuse of tasks. A taks is supposed to be short, not contain an infinite loop. It should *not* require additional synchronization, this is provided by ContinueWith, await etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if the tasks are supposed to be short, why is then there a `LongRunning` option in this enum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

What you're preaching is not specifically correct. Tasks ARE threads that are managed by the .Net's threadpool so you don't have to do it. They are nothing more than that.

Comment: @zaitsman the option exist *precisely* because tasks are supposed to be short. That's the default. Long tasks require special handling. And tasks are not threads, where did you get that idea? *All* docs, blog posts, MSDN articles, explain that tasks *run* on threads from the ThreadPool, which is why you should *not* block them for long because you tie up a shared resource

Comment: @zaitsman for example, [Task-based Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx): `In some ways, a task resembles a thread or ThreadPool work item, but at a higher level of abstraction.` Next paragraph `Behind the scenes, tasks are queued to the ThreadPool, which has been enhanced with algorithms that determine and adjust to the number of threads and that provide load balancing to maximize throughput. This makes tasks relatively lightweight, and you can create many of them to enable fine-grained parallelism.`

Comment: It says `lightweight`, meaning no overhead, not short. And of course you should never block them, it is possible to wait without blocking the thread (which is what you should do anyway if this is a consistent workflow).